# Need Suggestion: database connection class to connect to mysql using C#

Tags: c#, mysql, connection-string, dispose, static-variables

I've created database connection class just to open, close, and make a connection string. I named it `db_connections` . I created another class named  `db_operations` to do all CRUD database transactions.

My idea is: 
I just want to declare the connection string once (for this, assume I've got one form to input any database connection attributes, eg: server_name, db_name, etc).

All that I know C# does have global variable cmiiw, and my searching many suggest to use a static variable to store data. But some told me that using static variable is not safe.

All the code is using C# 4.0.

Here is the code for my connections class:

```
class db_connections : databases_abstract
{

    private static string dbname;
    private static string dbuser;
    private static string dbpass;
    private static string dbserver;

    public MySqlConnection mysqlConn;

    public static string DB_NAME
    {
        get
        {
            return dbname;
        }
        set
        {
            dbname = value;
        }
    }

    public static string DB_USER
    {
        get
        {
            return dbuser;
        }
        set
        {
            dbuser = value;
        }
    }

    public static string DB_PASSWORD
    {
        get
        {
            return dbpass;
        }
        set
        {
            dbpass = value;
        }
    }

    public static string DB_SERVER
    {
        get
        {
            return dbserver;
        }
        set
        {
            dbserver = value;
        }
    }


    protected override string db_make_connstring(string dbserver, string dbuser, string dbpass, string dbname)
    {
        //## Our connection string
        string connString = String.Format("server={0};user id={1}; password={2}; database={3}; pooling=false",
        dbserver, dbuser, dbpass, dbname);

        return connString;
    }

    public override Boolean db_open_connection()
    {
        try
        {
            //## Initialise the connection
            mysqlConn = new MySqlConnection(
                this.db_make_connstring(db_connections.dbserver, db_connections.dbuser,
                    db_connections.dbpass, db_connections.dbname)
                );
            if (mysqlConn != null)
            {
                mysqlConn.Close();
            }
            //## Open the connection
            mysqlConn.Open();

            return true;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "Error",
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            return false;
        }
    }

    public override void db_close_connection()
    {
        try
        {
            if (mysqlConn != null)
            {
                mysqlConn.Close();
                mysqlConn.Dispose();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception Ex)
        {
            System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(Ex.Message, "Error",
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK,
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Error);

        }

    }
}
```

From the database connection form I instantiated that class like this:

```
    db_connections db_conn = new db_connections();
    db_connections.DB_SERVER = txtDbServer.Text;
    db_connections.DB_NAME = txtDbName.Text;
    db_connections.DB_USER = txtDbUser.Text;
    db_connections.DB_PASSWORD = txtDbPass.Text;

    //##Just testing the connection
    //##Once the connection succes, the database setting cannot be opened again
    //##until the application is terminated or any really special event request
    if (db_conn.db_open_connection() == true)
    {
       MessageBox.Show("Successfully connect to the database!!");
       this.Owner.Controls["btnUpload"].Enabled = true;
       this.Owner.Controls["btnDb"].Enabled = false;
       this.Close();
    }
```

I want to know:

1. Is that true, using static variable not safe? if yes, any suggestions to refactor my code?
2. I concern using `mysqlConn.Dispose()`, inside every function in `db_operations` class, I just call `db_operations` class to open and close connection (not to create or modify the `connection string`). So is that enough just to use `mysqlConn.Close();` to close the connection?
3. Is there any suggestion to make my `db_connections` safer?

Comment: "Not safe" in what sense?

Comment: haha,i dont know pal, but kinda never feel safe every time i write a code, i need to explore more for every code i write, just to make sure i made a good code :D

Comment: -1: You are the one asking us whether this is safe.  You need to clarify what you mean by this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, statics are not generally unsafe. But you use them in a way they are not meant to be used. For instance, you create an instance of class db_connections, then assign values to the static properties of class db_connections, after that you use an object method of that class that in turn uses the static properties again. Static properties are in no way connected to a specific object instance of the class they are declared in. A static property is a bit like a global variable in PHP - in a given context (usually the whole application, per thread is also possible), it only exists once. So you can store configuration information i static properties of a class, but you have to keep in mind that you can keep only one information at any time. You could for instance not create two configurations for different databases. So whenever you change a static property, you change it for every piece of code accessing that property.

A small example on static properties:

```
public class TestClass
{

     public static string Text1 { get; set; }
     public string Text2 { get; set; }

     public void WriteText1()
     {
         Console.WriteLine(TestClass.Text1);
     }

     public void WriteText2()
     {
         Console.WriteLine(this.Text2);
     }
}



public class Program
{

   public static void Main(string[] args)
   {
       TestClass class1 = new TestClass;
       TestClass.Text1 = "Some Text";
       class1.Text2 = "More Text";

       class1.WriteText1();
       class1.WriteText2();

       TestClass class2 = new TestClass;
       TestClass.Text1 = "Another Text";
       class2.Text2 = "And a fourth text";

       class2.WriteText1();
       class2.WriteText2();

       class1.WriteText1();
   }
}
```

the output on this is:

```
Some Text
More Text
Another Text
And a fourth text
Another Text
```

the last call on class1.WriteText1() writes the same output as class2.WriteText1. Both objects, class1 and class2, access the same static property, Text1. This is different to instance properties like Text2. Both objects contain a property called Text2, but the values are different, they are part of an individual object. Change the value of that property for a single object and it is only changed within that object, other objects, while they have the same property, retain their own value.

Comment: hi @Dirk Trilsbeek, superb answer anyway...  <br/>
> But you use them in a way they are not meant to be used
  <br/>
i agree with that, or maybe better to use **application configuration file** , to store this kind of information ?
<br/>
>Static properties are in no way connected to a specific object instance of the class they are declared in
  <br/>
i'm sory pal, can you more specific explain this(still confused) ?

Comment: a static property is not connected to any object. If you have an object that has properties and you create a second object, the properties of the second object are part of that object. The two objects don't share their properties, the property values can be different. Two objects accessing static properties actually access the same properties. If one object changes these properties, they are also changed for everyone else using them.

Comment: i added a small code sample on static properties and what i meant by "not connected to a specific object".

Answer (score 0):

Use the application configuration file to store this type of information. If using asp.net, you can use Web.Config file to store all your connection strings. If you are using Winforms, then you can use App.config to do the same.

You can read more about the ConnectionStrings section here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms254494.aspx

And you just access this information using the ConfigurationManager class as so:

```
MySqlConnection con = new MySqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DBConnString"].ConnectionString);
```

This is also a good source to learn how to define your connection strings for all types of databases and drivers: http://www.connectionstrings.com/Articles/Show/store-connection-string-in-web-config

Comment: hey @lcarus, thx for quick response :D, and for a good link ofcourse :D